# Why are some git commits hidden inside the cygwin shell?

Tags: git, cygwin, msysgit

One of my colleagues recently noticed a discrepancy between the normal `git log` command, and and the following alias:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

After a bit of poking, we found out that it may be related to the cygwin bash.

Here are our findings:

- `git log --graph`

  all commits visible
- `git log --oneline`

  some commits missing... okay! let's prepare an error report by redirecting the output to a text file:
- `git log --oneline > test.txt`

  Alas, all commits are visible in `test.txt` ?!?
  Let's investigate further by taking apart the alias. Removing color codes:
- `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%h - %d %s (%cr) <%an>'`

  some commits missing. So it must be one of the variables...

[... some frobnications later ...]

- `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%h - %d %s (%cr)'`

  all commits visible
- `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%h - %d %s <%an>'`

  all commits visible

It seems to break after certain *combinations* of variables. In this case `(%cr) <%an>`

I also tried the same repository on linux and on there, it works as expected (i.e. all commits are shown in the log).

We would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Did you try to avoid '`>`' and '`<`' in your alias definition, to see if the command runs better in your Cygwin session?

Comment: Removing the angle brackets did not solve the problem. Strangely though, now one additional commit show up in the log. But they are still not all there.

Comment: As another datapoint, you might want to try `msysgit` from a `cmd.exe` prompt and a MinGW/MSYS bash shell to narrow down the problem.  BTW, don't use msysgit from Cygwin -- use Cygwin's git.

Answer (score 1):

Try these to get closer to the cause:

- use cygwin with a different terminal, say xterm or mintty.
- set (or unset?) `$PAGER` and see how that affects the bug.
- if `$PAGER` is `less`, save the log from inside `less` (<kbd>S</kbd>), and/or <kbd>-R</kbd> to turn on /off processing of ANSI escapes, if you have color on.
- try with --no-color, if you have color on
- check your locale settings, `$LC_ALL`, `$LANG` etc.  try

`LANG=C git log` etc